# How to pass page information as parameter to asp.net website, on which it is accessed?

Tags: asp.net

On a page in a website, I am giving a link to the login page of my asp.net website.
While i click on the link, I want to capture some information which is available on the page and pass it to my website's first page. Is there any way I can do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the required values in **QueryString** in the Url.

Check this: [HttpRequest.QueryString Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.querystring%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Also, You can use LinkButton and Handle its click event. On the Click Event you can set the required information in **Cookie or Session** as per you need.

Comment: The page on which i am giving link to my website is a google apps page. Somehow i need to capture info displayed on this page.

Comment: @hitesh.gawhade In that case you can set the required values in QueryString in the url.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use the Query String , if the data is small , you can get the information on query string from this [Link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5876/Passing-variables-between-pages-using-QueryString)

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to capture the State. Follow these tutorials or google it for State Management tutorial. here are some:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/331962/A-Beginner-s-Tutorial-on-ASP-NET-State-Management

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/492397/State-Management-in-ASP-NET-Introduction

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx